# How to use strong labels in image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification, attention-mechanism

I have a dataset where I have localized pixel-level annotations of a dataset of cancer vs non-cancer.

Which deep learning methods can I use to optimize the model to focus on the localized regions of the image and ignore the regions outside the annotations?

Additionally, I have a set of images with only image level labels. Is there a way to use both localized labels (strong labels) and image level labels (weak labels) in the same model?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the matter of specific architecture, if this is what you are asking. To focus only on cancerous regions you could simply only compute the loss function over this region, and not the background, for example implementation of a DiceLoss and MaskedDiceLoss in MONAI library have this option built-in^[1,2]. Otherwise you could weight different regions of the image during loss computation (e.g. 1 to cancerous region, 0.7 for region of organ of interest and 0.5 for the background).

As for the second question, the most straightforward way is to use separate loss for these images within the same architecture. For example, you could have a standard Unet neural network with:

- standard segmentation head output and,
- additional classification head

both heads are working during inference (or you could switch off the second head), but during training you only use segmentation head to compute the loss, when segmentation annotation is available.

Classification head could be added to different places of the network, into the bottleneck, or after the segmentation output, or separately. In example below^[3] (I am a co-author of the paper) we output probabilities for the classification score just before the segmentation output:

[image]

1. https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/losses.html#diceloss
2. https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/losses.html#maskeddiceloss
3. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1361841521001006